# How does storage of old events affect performance in esper?

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

How does storage of old events affect the performance in esper?
For eg - What is the effect on performance if we store 10 old events and how  will the performance change if we store 100 old events. Will there be any change?
I want to know the memory usage in esper. Where do the old events get stored?

Answer (score 2):

Engine retains events in memory only when EPL has one of these:

- a data window
- a EPL pattern
- a match recognize pattern

When event falls out of data window or pattern the JVM can garbage collect it. Store is memory for Esper and other places for EsperHA.

Comment: hey, thanks @goodie! But how do they affect performance if the number of old events stored is increased? Do you have any idea?